# Present and past perfect dilemma

Tags: grammaticality, present-perfect, past-perfect, simple-past-vs-past-perfect, perfect-aspect

This sentence is giving me trouble:

> For several days I (have/had) not had the chance to see her until a
>   few hours ago.

I think *had* is correct because the time reference is *a few hours ago*, which is in the past.

What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are quite right. *A few hours ago* is your Reference time, and you are speaking of the several days *before* that, so the past perfect is required.

Since you're working with two different time phrases, your sentence will be a little clearer if you rearrange the pieces so that the Reference time is established **before** your verb; either:

> For several days, until a few hours ago, I had not had the chance to see her.

Or

> Until a few hours ago, I had not had the chance to see her for several days.

Comment: I prefer dashes to mark the temporal adverbials as having equal independent standing: For several days - (indeed,) until (just) a few hours ago - I had not had the chance to see her.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  I agree, under those circumstances; but if in the larger context *a few hours ago* is of secondary interest I'll parenthesize with commas -- but I would then probably prefer the second version. It's really a matter of what's coming up in the next sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using 'have' as otherwise it would sound weird having to say 'had' twice in such close vicinity.